# build.gradle.kts following githubs guide: Configuring Gradle for use with GitHub Packages. But it fails finding the "from" function

Tags: kotlin, github, gradle, package

I have a sample kotlin project that i am trying to get send to github as a package. Below is the contents of my buid.gradle.kts file. I am following this guide: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-packages#example-using-kotlin-dsl-for-a-single-package-in-the-same-repository

But i can find any help as to why this error happens with the "from" function"

[image]

**buid.gradle.kts content:**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.31"
    `maven-publish`
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY")
            credentials {
                username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") as String? ?: System.getenv("USERNAME")
                password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") as String? ?: System.getenv("TOKEN")
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        register("gpr") {
            from(components["java"]) //This part fails with a Unresolved reference. None of the following 
                                     //candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
        }
    }
}

group = "me.jeppe"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnit()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching wide and far it appears that i need to write this:

```
register("gpr", MavenPublication::class)
```

instead of:

```
register("gpr")
```